# How to upload an image with multer to Google Cloud in Express js

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have an issue, I succeed to upload a picture to a folder, but how to upload to Google Cloud?
Here is my code:

```js
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
      const original = file.originalname; //original name yg di upload
      const ext = original.substr(original.length - 5);//ambil 5 string terakhir pasti itu sudah termasuk extension
      const regex = /[^\w\s]/g;//temukan selain word/kata atau whitepsace
      const dot = ext.search(regex);
      cb(null, uniqueSuffix + ext.substr(dot));//ambil setelah . sebagai extension
    }
  });

  const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    // jika jpg dan png maka di terima, selain itu riject
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
    }
  }

  upload_image = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5},
    fileFilter: fileFilter
  });

  module.exports = upload_image;
```

What I need is only change/upload to Google Cloud.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You couldn't only change folder to upload file to google cloud.
I assume you want upload file to google drive, and you should use google drive api to upload image to google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the solution
the basic idea is, first i upload picture to /upload folder, after that i upload from /upload to google cloud, last i delete file in /upload folder, but for delete i put in the end of middle ware cause if delete after upload to google cloud, file is deleted before upload to google cloud finish

this my complete code
upload to /upload folder

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
      const original = file.originalname; //original name yg di upload
      const ext = original.substr(original.length - 5);//ambil 5 string terakhir pasti itu sudah termasuk extension
      const regex = /[^\w\s]/g;//temukan selain word/kata atau whitepsace
      const dot = ext.search(regex);
      cb(null, uniqueSuffix + ext.substr(dot));//ambil setelah . sebagai extension
    }
  });

  const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    // jika jpg dan png maka di terima, selain itu riject
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
    }
  }

  upload_image = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5},
    fileFilter: fileFilter
  });

  module.exports = upload_image;
```

this is code to upload to google cloud

```
const util = require('util')
const gc = require('../../config')
const bucket = gc.bucket('mybucket')//bucket name di google drive
const path = require('path')

const { format } = util

//promise di panggil di midleware
const uploadImage = (files) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  //perlu di looping di sini karena yang di kirim berupa array
  let arrayPicture = [];
  files.forEach(element => {

    const {filename} = element
    // console.log(filename);
    const picture = path.join(__dirname,'../../uploads',filename);

    //ini peruntah untuk uplaod
    bucket.upload(picture);

    // ini yang di kirim ke return
        // const publicUrl = format(
          // `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${filename}`
        // )

    arrayPicture.push(picture);
  });

  resolve(arrayPicture);

  reject(err=>(err))
})

module.exports = uploadImage
```

this is my code to delete in /upload folder

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (req,res,next)=>{
    // const arrayPicture = req.picture;
    const removeImage = (arrayPicture)=> new Promise( (resolve,rejects)=>{
        arrayPicture.forEach(element => {
            fs.unlink(element,(err)=>{
                if(err){
                  console.log(err);
                  res.status(500).json({
                    message:"remove data from folder fail",
                    error: err, status:500,
                  });
                }
              });
        });

        const message = "unlink succed"
        resolve(message);
        rejects(err=>(err))
    });

    removeImage(req.picture)
        .then(result=>{
            // res.send(result);
            next();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
              error: err, status:500, message:"unlink unsucced"
            });
          })

}
```

please note that i send array of picture name in req.picture with location directory

and this is my route midleware

```
router.post("/", checkAuth, checkProfile, UploadService.array('productImage',4), PostImageToCloud
    ,ProductPostController,ProductQuantityPostController ,ProductImagePostController ,RemoveImageWasUpload
    ,ProductResource);
```